# How to play .mts file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Currently im working with a wifi-camera device,  which is able to send only videos in **.mts format**.
As i have investigated in google, it leads to conclusion that it is not possible to play the video in iPhone or may be using Objective C.

Now my problem what is,

**There is still many paid applications that allows us to play .mts files**

```
PlayerXtreme is able to run files in almost any video format. It has currently the following formats covered:

3gp, asf, avi, divx, dv, dat, flv, gxf, m2p, m2ts, m2v, m4v, mkv, moov, mov, mp4, mpeg, mpeg1, mpeg2, mpeg4, mpg, mpv, mt2s, mts, mxf, ogm, ogv, ps, qt, rm, rmvb, ts, vob, webm, wm, wmv
```

See the application: [iTunes app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playerxtreme-media-player-movies-streaming/id456584471?mt=8)

Player i m curently trying is ***AVPlayer lib***

How can i start the coding to get this done in my app also?

Currently I'm trying solve by adding some python scripts to my project as a build.. and calling the same for converting to mp4 format.. anyone worked on py-ObjC Together in XCode pls give some idea..

Comment: You're going to need to show us your code that isn't working so we can try to help you fix it. Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask as general a question as you're asking here.

Comment: It is not gerenic question as you said.. please see answer by @Leo and help me out

Comment: Im not trying to stream.. I wanted to transfer to my application and play inside application itself..

Answer (score 4):

MTS is a container format. You need to know what the video and audio codecs are, and see whether VideoToolbox and AudioToolbox (the underlying frameworks of AVPlayer) support those codecs.

Assuming H264 for video and AAC or AC3 for audio, libavcodec (part of ffmpeg) supports the MTS container. You can use that to demux the video and audio streams, and then use `VTDecompressionSession` and `AudioQueueNewOutput` (I think, I haven’t used that API in a while).

Comment: I have checked..audio is AAC but H264 is not the video codec.. is there any way to find out video format?

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i <file>` to get info about the streams in your file.

Comment: where i can add this line.. in terminal?

Comment: Yes. Install ffmpeg in terminal and use it.

Comment: will let you know after.. thats a lot